# Function template overloading (different return value type)

Tags: c++, templates

I'm reading [C++ Templates: The Complete Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201734842), and in "13.7 Partial Specialization of Function Templates" author said:

> To overload function templates, their function parameters must differ in some material way. Consider a function template R convert(T const&) where R and T are template parameters. We may very well want to specialize this template for R = void, but this cannot be done using overloading.

It could be done using function template overloading, right? Such as:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename R>
R convert(T const&) { std:: cout << "R convert(T const&)\n"; }
template <typename T>
void convert(T const&) { std:: cout << "void convert(T const&)\n"; }

int main()
{
    convert(0);
}
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/tJM3im) here, result is:

> void convert(T const&)

What does author really mean?

Comment: The author is probably referring to C++'s lack of support for overloading on return type.

Comment: @nix But it's supported by function template overloading.

Comment: I think that you're running into some UB that your compiler isn't smart enough to warn about.  Try adding a return statement to the first `convert` (so that it will compile`), then replace the call to `convert(0)` with `int i=convert(0)`.  It won't compile.

Comment: @nix It won't compile because you can only call the first overload by explicitly specifying the template arguments. Apart from missing return statement, this code is fine.

Comment: The compiler can't deduce `R` for the first template, so it's never selected.

Comment: @nix Because author is talking about the difference between "partial specialization" and "overloading", but I think this cannot be done by specialization too. So I can't get the point of the above context from the book.

Comment: "Partial Specialization of Function Templates" - interesting title for a chapter

Comment: @MattMcNabb The author is talking about the possibility and reason to adopt "Partial Specialization of Function Templates" in standards at this chapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a class template partial specialization:

```
template<class U, class V> class T { };

template<class V> class T<void, V> { };
```

When you write `T<void, int>`, the partial specialization will be used.

Now consider a function template:

```
template <typename R, typename T>
R convert(T const&) { return /* something */; }
```

Note that the order of `R` and `T` are swapped in the template parameter list above. This is probably how such a template would be written - you write `convert<R>(something)`, explicitly specifying the destination type while letting the source type be deduced by the compiler.

Now suppose you want `convert<void>(something)` to do something different. You can't do it with an overload:

```
template <typename T>
void convert(T const&) { }
```

If you write `convert(something)` - which would previously be ill-formed, it will go to your new overload, because the compiler can't deduce `R` for the first template. But if you write `convert<void>(something)` or even `convert<void, T>(something)`, it would still go to the original template. To make it worse, something like `convert<int>(1)` is now ill-formed because it's ambiguous.

In other words, you can't make `convert<void, T>(something)` use a different implementation than `convert<int, T>(something)`, whereas you can do this with class template partial specializations.

Comment: I thought author is suggesting that partial specialization of function templates can do this...my misunderstanding?

Comment: @songyuanyao There's no such thing as function template partial specializations in C++, period. The authors seem to be discussing some cases which can be solved by a hypothetical modification to the standard to permit function template partial specializations, but the standard was never changed in that way.